# How do i create a line breaker when writing a file in Java?

Tags: java

I'm working on a code that takes in a couple of inputs and re-write them into a .txt file of my creation but to my dismay the output file can not contain a line-breaker even with the appropriate formatting. I'm using Formatter(java.util)

```
public void file(Scanner s, Formatter f){
    String s1 = s.nextLine();
    if (!"end".equals(s1)){
        f.format("%s\n%s", s1, "  ");
        file(s,f);
    }
    f.close();
}

public void file(Scanner input,Formatter f,int state){
    String s1 = input.nextLine();
    int loopStop = 0;
    if (state == 1){
        file(input, f);
    } else {
        while (!"end".equals(s1) && loopStop<11){
            f.format("%s\n\n%s", s1, "  ");
            s1 = input.nextLine();
            loopStop++;
        }
        f.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what OS are you doing this on? `\n` only works on Unix systems. For Windows, you'd need `\r\n`

Comment: Try `System.getProperty("line.separator")` for line separator that is OS specific.

Comment: System.getProperty("line.seperator"); or use a BufferedWriter and use its newLine method

Comment: @braj You need to make that an answer so I can up vote it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use '%n' for the platform-specific line separator :

```
f.format("%s%n%n%s", s1, "  ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Read it here about [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) with complete list of System properties.

The System class maintains a Properties object that describes the configuration of the current working environment.

> "line.separator"   -  Sequence used by operating system to **separate lines in text files**

---

Try with [System.lineSeparator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) as well that states:

> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns the same value - the initial value of the system property line.separator.
>
> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it returns "\r\n".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Windows, you need to use `\r\n` which is the proper combination of line-break in Windows or simply use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` to get the newline combination.